# Matching specific lengths with regexp in Matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, matching

String matching question in Matlab.
if i have a matrix

```
a = ['thehe'];
str = {'the','he'};
match = regexp(a,str);
```

the output is match =

```
[1]    [1x2 double]
```

because it found 'he' twice and 'the' once 
how can i make it so it looks from left to right of my string a and 
only matches 'the' once and 'he' once?

Comment: This is an oversimplified example.  What if you had `a = 'the hero goes to the moon';`?  What should be the desired output?  Did you only want to return the first occurrence of `he`? Also the first occurrence of `the`?

Comment: in that example if my str only contains {the,he} then I want to only return the index of the word 'the' and I would want no index to return for the word 'he'

Comment: So you want to find **all** matches for the `the` keyword wholly for the first pattern... and **all** matches for the `he` word wholly? So would the expected output be 2 matches for `the` and no matches for `he`?  These kinds of questions I shouldn't have to ask. These should be clearly defined in your problem statement to prevent us from being confused, and to allow you to get an answer faster.

Comment: oh yes two matches for the word the, and no matches for he. sorry I did not notice the second 'the' your sentence example.

Comment: That's why I asked.  Your string only has one occurrence of each.  When there are two or more, your problem statement becomes ambiguous.

Comment: One more... suppose we had `thehehehehehehethe thethethehehehe`... what is the expected output?

Comment: 5 occurrences of the word 'the' and 9 occurrences of the word 'he'

Comment: That contradicts your problem statement.  `thehe` you said should only return one `the` and one `he`... yet in the example I gave you, the logic you stated would count `he` twice.... so which one is it?

Comment: thats the problem I am having. In my problem statement I want it to return it only once for the and once for he but it is counting he twice which is not what I want

Comment: So is the expected output in my second example supposed to return `the` and `he` only once?  What about the first example?

Comment: in your first example a = 'the hero goes to the moon'. i want it to return 'the' twice and 'he' zero times because the word 'he' is not in your sentence.

Comment: Yeah it is... **he**ro.  If you can decompose `thehe` into an instance of `the` and `he`, then by the same logic, you could decompose `hero` into `he` and `ro`.  I'm giving up, sorry.

Comment: okay thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

To answer the explicit question, from [the documentation for regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) you can specify the `once` search option:

```
a = 'thehe';
str = {'the','he'};
match = regexp(a,str, 'once');
```

Which returns:

```
match = 

    [1]    [2]
```

Where `match` is a `1x2 cell` array whose cell value(s) correspond to the first index of the match in `a` for each cell of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from what the ambiguously described details I'v read, that you want the indexes of non-interleaved occurences of `the` and `he`, means 1, and 4.

```
a = ['thehe'];
str = {'the';'[^t]he'};
match = regexp(a,str)
```

after this print the two results.

```
a(match{1}:match{1}+2)

ans =

the
```

and

```
a(match{2}+1:match{2}+2)

ans =

he
```

---

no third occurence !

```
a(match{3})

??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```